# Determining the Equation of a Graph based on points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Given that an polynomial has the points $(\pm\sqrt{3},0),(\pm5,11)$, the degree is greater than $2$ and it has an even degree, can the equation of the polynomial be determined. I tried just plugging in values, but that didn't work. I do have a picture, but I want the equation that fills in that gap at the bottom:
[image: Impartial graph]

**EDIT:**
I have determined that the vertex is $(0,-0.25)$. How do I progress?

Answer (score 0):

If you have number of points equal to the degree, look at [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: But I don't know the degree, so I can't use it. It may be 10, 12 even 14

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number of even-order polynomials that fit the data, found by doing a least-squares fit to the polynomial model.

Here are just some of them:

[image]

Comment: Is there a general form to the equations?

Comment: What software did you run to make those graphs?

Comment: *Mathematica*..

Comment: But how did you get the equations?

Comment: @QuoteDave:  Simple curve fitting with different numbers of even polynomial rank.

Comment: Sorry, I meant like the code you use in Mathematica